# Reduced chi-squared value for noiseless spectra

Tags: spectroscopy, statistics, data-analysis

I am fitting synthetic spectral data. This is data in the form of a gaussian lineshape. However, although the fit looks appropriate, the value of the reduced chi-squared parameter: 
$$\chi^2_{\rm red} = \frac{1}{\nu}\sum\frac{(O-E)^2}{\sigma^2} \,, $$

is a lot larger than 1.0, the value for a desirable fit. Since I do not have any noise, the value of $\sigma$ in the above equation is unknown. How can I lower my reduced chi-squared value?

Comment: Would [stats.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand how you have calculated a reduced chi-squared using the formula in your question if you don't have a value for $\sigma$?

Obviously, the value of the reduced chi-squared is smaller if you provide a better model that more closely fits your data.

Finally, if you do not know the value of $\sigma$ for your data, then you can still use a Pearson's chi-squared to do the fit (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test ), replacing $\sigma^2$ with $E$. You can then examine the residuals to see if they show any trend or asymmetry that might indicate a problem with the model, but without an independent estimate of $\sigma$ you cannot evaluate the quality of the fit.

If you know that the binned data obey Poissonian statistics, then $\sigma^2$ is the number of counts in the bin (so long as that is more than about 10 in all bins). I imagine though, that this *is* what your fitting software has assumed.

If on the other hand you are saying that you believe your model *is* correct, but that you need plausible chi-squared values to estimate parameter uncertainties, then you could apply a uniform $\sigma$ to each point such that the reduced chi-squared becomes unity.

Comment: @ Rob Jeffries - the part that I didn't include is that the fitting program automatically derived the reduced chi-squared value from the fit that I applied. Thus, since the value of the reduced chi-squared is large, I must conclude that the model doesn't fit the underlying data in a satisfactory manner. I was under the impression that Pearson's chi-squared test was only applicable to categorical data.

Comment: @stars83clouds Without understanding how the reduced chi-squared has been calculated, you cannot possibly conclude that. We might suspect that it has used Pearson's chi-squared, but unless your data happens to have $\sigma^2 \simeq E$ (maybe it does if your data obey Poisson stats?) then the value of chi-squared is not meaningful.

Comment: @ Rob Jeffries - and therein lies my problem. I have no idea how the fitting program determined the value for the reduced chi-squared parameter from the fit. I have the datapoints and model fit points, so I will try and do it by hand. However, I am unsure what value should be used for \sigma. Is this simply the standard deviation of the error? Yes, the data should obey Poisson statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Each observation should have some error (sigma). This is a physical fact. You would have to use the estimated sigma if you do not know. Most probably your estimated sigma are low. Also you should use the correct(parent) mean and sigma for the Gaussian in the numerator.

Comment: I don't have error from the synthetic spectral data. If I assume that its associated error has a normal distribution, then the variance, \sigma^2, will be 1. Is that a suitable approximation?

Comment: No, there is an error. I am close to getting the Pearson chi-squared test, as pointed out by Rob Jeffries, give me a reasonable representation of the fit.

Comment: The programs normally operate in three modes. (a)The one in which you supply errors sigma for each data point. (b) In which you assume errors associated with statistical fluctuation in this case sigma equals sq root of counts. (c) You don't supply errors. The program takes all sigma as 1 as you noted. In this last case what you get is not reduce chi sq but sample(experimental) sigma which is your case. However if you are getting a result that's fine.